# How to force translate i18n in some specific text (variable) in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js, internationalization, vue-i18n

In normal context, we just attach translation property to a variable like **:**

```
this.name = this.$t('language.name');
```

But I want to specific it in a specific language sometime( ex: in French).
Can we do something like this in `vue.js` ?

```
this.name = this.$t('language.name', locale: fr);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the old package [`kazupon/vue-i18n`](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n), the following should be possible:

```
$t(key, locale)
```

---

When using the successor-package [`intlify/vue-i18n-next`](https://github.com/intlify/vue-i18n-next), the answer depends on if you are using Vue I18n's **Legacy API** or the newer **Composition API**:

---

Using **Legacy API** as described in the normal [setup guide](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/) the usages of the `t()` function are stated [here](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/api/legacy.html#vuei18ntranslation).

This means you can still use the following call to translate a key to a specific locale (e.g. 'fr'):

```
$t(key, locale)
```

Example:

```
$t('message.key', 'fr')
```

---

Using the **Composition API** by calling `createI18n()` with the option `legacy: false` (as described [here](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/composition.html)), the usages of the `t()` function are different as stated [here](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/api/composition.html#composertranslation). You can no longer pass the locale-string as the second parameter, but the locale can be handed over inside a [`TranslateOptions` object](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/api/general.html#translateoptions). Unfortunately, there is no `t(key,TranslateOptions`) variant, but only the following variants:

```
$t(key, plural, TranslateOptions)
$t(key, defaultMsg, TranslateOptions)
$t(key, interpolations, TranslateOptions)
```

So the easiest solution would be e.g.:

```
$t('message.key', 1, { locale: 'fr' })
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, it worked. Can you share me documents or anything related to this topic?

Comment: @DFXNguyễn No problem! I've actually realised, that there are two modes of usage for Vue I18n: the Legacy API and the newer Composition API. I assume you are using the latter one. I've updated my answer to state solutions for both modes and added links to the documentation.