# How to display the translation of a key in a specified language with i18n (not necessarily the current language?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, i18next

In i18n, `$t("myKey")` displays the translation of `myKey` in current language. But what if I want the translation of `myKey` in a specified language?

Something like `$t("myKey", "de")`, except this doesn't work.

Is there any way to achieve this though?

Comment: Why not hardcoding it in that case? If you don't want to make it dynamic, write it statically.

Comment: check out this example https://codesandbox.io/s/example-i18n-k2431ywqm3?file=/locales/fr.json

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force translate i18n in some specific text (variable) in Vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68434953/how-to-force-translate-i18n-in-some-specific-text-variable-in-vuejs)

Comment: @RohìtJíndal it does indeed! Thank you.